# .bash_login file not loading in new Terminal windows or after I close Terminal and reopen it

Tags: macos, terminal

My .bash_login file is not loading when I create new terminal windows or when I close Terminal and reopen it. I have to run:

source ~/.bash_login

everytime in order for my aliases inside .bash_login to work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

`./bash_login` is read whenever you login (restart computer, restart desktop or connecting to a remote computer etc.) and creating a new terminal is not logging in. If you want to load your aliases every time you open a new terminal, you need to put them in `/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: @skaterdav85: ~/.bashrc, but that shouldn't be the problem: Terminal does (at least for me) open new windows (and tabs) as login shells.

Comment: The problem was that I have oh-my-zsh installed so I didnt realize bash and zsh were 2 separate things. I had to edit the .zshrc file and add my aliases there. I guess that is the equivalent to the .bashrc file but for zsh. Now I need to figure out what bash and zsh are lol

Comment: I just realized this question was tagged for `osx`. I never used a `terminal` on `osx` but if it's similar to the one I have on my `ubuntu` system, it doesn't login when I fire up a new terminal unless you check `run command as a login shell` option from settings.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ~/.bash_profile file? If so, it'll use that in preference to ~/.bash_login. From the bash man page:

```
When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-
interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and exe-
cutes  commands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
After  reading  that   file,   it   looks   for   ~/.bash_profile,
~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and exe-
cutes commands from the first one that  exists  and  is  readable.
The  --noprofile  option  may be used when the shell is started to
inhibit this behavior.
```